# Making one copy of complex type from 2 webservices

Tags: c#, web-services, types, proxy

In C# (other .Net OOP languages as well), I have 2 webservices. Svc1 returns a complex datatype which becomes the parameter for svc2. Note that it is the same complex type.

Now, I create the 2 proxy classes of these 2 webservices. Which means the same type gets generated twice.

How can I make sure that in 2 proxies only one copy of that type is there? You may assume same or different namespaces of 2 webservices.

Answer (score 1):

Generate the two proxies at the same time:

```
svcutil http://example.com/svc1?wsdl http://example.com/svc2?wsdl
```

If the type is really the same (name and namespace) in both services it will generate only a single proxy class for the client.

Yet another possibility is to generate the proxy class for the first service:

```
svcutil http://example.com/svc1?wsdl
```

compile the generated `.cs` file into an assembly for example `MyAssembly.dll` and use the [/reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) option when importing the second service:

```
svcutil /reference:MyAssembly.dll http://example.com/svc2?wsdl
```

This will look for same types in the WSDL and the supplied assembly.

Comment: curious though.. in case webservices are in different namespaces, what would be best approach to attain the same?

Comment: You can't attain the same if different namespaces. You will need to manually hack around generated proxies.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar issue recently; I haven't tried Darin's advice.

Miguel Castro of [IDesign](http://www.idesign.net) gave a great presentation on "WCF the Manual Way… the Right Way" at the March 2009 DevConnections. In that he showed how to reuse service contracts and proxies. From my notes:

- One assembly for Service/Data Contracts

  - Shared between client & server
- One assembly for services

  - Permits changing host and reusing
- One assembly for proxies

  - Reuse among clients
- Separate application for hosting
- Do not use "Add Service Reference"
- Service (POCO) project references Contracts (interfaces) project and System.ServiceModel
- Client Proxies assemblies reference Contracts assembly but **not** Service project
- Client applications instantiate proxies

Our company hasn't made the move to WCF yet, but this looks like the way to go (to me).

**EDIT:** I found an [article by Mr. Castro](http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?QuickID=0809101) on this.